# Remove non-int from rows in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to teach myself Python for data analysis and to practice I'm working on analyzing a CSV file containing 27k survey responses.

The responses take the form of "# - Rating" (For example: "10 - Extremely Interested")

Would anyone be able to tell me how would I go about removing everything but the numerical value so that I could plot this data with matplotlib?

Thank you :)

Edit: My apologies, here is the code for the df I'm working with:

```
likely_recc = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', usecols = (['How likely are you to recommend this product to a friend?']))
```

Comment: The easy way is `field.split()[0]` to grab the first word.

Comment: you tagged pandas so I assumed you were working with a dataframe. is that true? showing us your code, ideally as a [mre] would be very helpful.

Comment: Added, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```py
df['col'].str.split(' ').str[0].astype(int)
```

Take a look at the pandas docs on [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) for more information.

Comment: Getting: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'I'

Comment: Got this to work by removing ".astype(int)"

Comment: seems like your data isn't super clean. you'll need to deal with this some other way. the type conversion (`.astype(int)`) is critical if you're going to be working with the data as values. so you probably need to track down what's happening in the rows that aren't numbers and decide how to handle them.

Comment: If it's something silly like the option for 1 actually has the value "I" (capital i) then you could use replace before the type conversion, e.g. `df['col'].str.split(' ').str[0].replace({"I", "1"}).astype(int)`

Comment: Yeah I've been running into this issue for the last hour. It's my first time trying to work with an actual data set. Sadly the above code also resulted in the same "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'I' " - Will update if I'm able to find a solution

Comment: you could find the rows that don't match a certain [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) pattern with [`pd.Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html), e.g.`df[~df.col.str.match(r'[0-9]+ ')]`

Answer (score 0):

```
input_array = ["10 - Extremely Interested", "9 - Very Interested"]

only_my_numbers = []
for element in input_array:
    # element.split("-") will split based on "-"
    # But it will will have trailing space. Remove that with strip()

    print(element.split("-")[0].strip())
    
    only_my_numbers.append(element.split("-")[0].strip())
```